# Installable trigger onFormSubmit in Sheets template not starting with copy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I am creating a google sheets template that pairs with google forms to create reporting capabilities off of form responses. In one of my scripts in the google sheets template is an `onFormSubmit()` trigger. It is intended to start when a new form is linked to the sheet template. The problem is it doesn't seem to start from a copy of the google sheets template or when the script is run for the first time. Any insights? I've researched the difference between installable and simple triggers but am not finding a clear answer.

```
function autoEmails() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = s.getSheetByName("Report Builder 2");
  var emailOneOn = ss.getRange("K3").getValue();
  var emailOne = ss.getRange("J4").getValue();
  var emailTwoOn = ss.getRange("N3").getValue();
  var emailTwo = ss.getRange("M4").getValue();
  var responseOne = ss.getRange("I5").getValue();
  var responseTwo = ss.getRange("L5").getValue();


  /*Logger.log(emailOneOn);
  Logger.log(emailOne);
  Logger.log(emailTwoOn);
  Logger.log(emailTwo);
  */

  if(emailOneOn == "On" && emailTwoOn =="On") {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailOne,"New Request" , responseOne);
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTwo,"New Request" , responseTwo);
      Logger.log("Both On")    
    }

  else if(emailOneOn == "On") {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailOne,"New Request" , responseOne);
    Logger.log("One on")
  }

  else if(emailTwoOn == "On") {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTwo,"New Request" , responseTwo);
    Logger.log("two on")
  }

  else{
    Logger.log("Both Off")

  }

}

function trigger() {

  var formId = FormApp.getActiveForm().getId();
  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('autoEmails')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

Everything else functions just fine when I run the `autoEmails()` function on its own. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The onFormSubmit trigger is generated when a user submits a form.

Comment: How does the copy get linked to the form?

Comment: Yes, I am aware. The template sheet is created and a form is created. The form is then linked to the sheet by choosing the sheet template as the response destination. Part of my issue also seems to be pulling the id of that form once attached.

Comment: Hello, can you share an example of your form and sheet with dummy data?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue I had.

Comment: @JoeIngersoll please post how you resolved it as an answer for documentation purposes.

Comment: function trigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('autoEmails')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}

Comment: I had to run the function in each new template and it established a trigger for that template.